# Why is the Euler characteristic a topological invariant that is independent of the triangulation?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

In Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces", in the proof of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem he gives 2 propositions he does not prove, namely:

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a compact connected surface, then
> $\chi(S)$ assumes one of the values $2,0,-2,...$. Additionally, if
> $S'\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is another compact surface with
> $\chi(S)=\chi(S')$, then $S$ is homeomorphic to $S'$.

and

> If $R \subset S$ is a regular region of a surface $S$, then the
> Euler-Poincaré characterestic does not depend on the triangulation of
> $R$. Hence, it can be denoted as $\chi(R)$.

I struggle to find proofs of these two statements that do not involve homology theory, can any of you maybe recommend one that is fairly "elementary"? I assume even a general outline of the proof goes beyond the scope of a comment here.

Answer (score 4):

For the special case of a compact surface $S$, one can prove invariance of Euler characteristic by the following steps.

**Step 1:** Prove that the Euler charactersitic of a triangulation of $S$ is invariant under subdivision of that triangulation.

**Step 2:** Prove that any two triangulations of $S$ have subdivisions which are simplicially isomorphic.

Step 1 is not too hard to do by some kind of induction argument.

Step 2 on the other hand is quite hard. It is more-or-less equivalent in difficulty to Rado's Theorem saying that every surface has a triangulation.

There are other special cases where this same 2-step method works. For example it works for compact 3-dimensional manifolds, using a much, much harder theorem of Moise which generalizes Rado's Theorem.

Unfortunately, there are examples of topological spaces for which Step 2 fails completely. So, in general, there is no hope for it: you'll just have to lock yourself in a room and learn singular homology theory.

Comment: I used the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem to show that every surface has a triangulation(since that is necessary for Gauss-Bonnet as well). Is there any way to use that?

Comment: You need more than just existence of a triangulation. You need a way to relate two triangulations.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen any Euler's characteristic without something involving homological algebra (or generalization of homological algebra such as triangulated categories). Check the part generalization in this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) (the French one is even clearer).

It is very much not probable that you will find a proof that does not use it. I see two possibles scenarios:

- You use homological algebra with our saying it and you make it look like it does not look like it.
- You use a restriction of the cases you study, like you only consider polyhedra or something like that and in this case you could try a combinatorial proof as Euler did for its proof of [Euler-Poincaré formula](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/model/euler.html).

So you should try to study basics of homological algebra (it is very useful in general) and how homology is computed for CW-complexes, and how does the Euler-Poincaré's characteristic can be computed on such sets.

When you have done that, it will become very clear to you why it is a topological invariant.

Comment: I found a way to express $\chi$ through Lefschetz indices, would that in any way help me with showing that $\chi$ is a topological invariant?